# Set OnItemClickListener in my RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to set one **OnItemClickListener** or something similar in my RecycleView adapter to toast the name of my items.

I tried a lot of things but I never works with adapters and it's a bit hard for me solve all conflics trying to use internet exemples,

Can someone help me implement it?   **Thanks in advance**

### HERE MY ADAPTER

```
package com.example.anonymous.mh4;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Anonymous on 22/02/2018.
 */

public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

    private List<Monster> feedItemList;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Monster> feedItemList) {
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }




    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)  {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listviewitemmonster, null);
        CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i)  {
        Monster feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);

        //Render image using Picasso library
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getIcon())
                    .error(R.drawable.unknown)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.unknown)
                    .into(customViewHolder.imageView);

        //Setting text view title
        customViewHolder.textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getName()));

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
    }

    class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected ImageView imageView;
        protected TextView textView;


        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imglayout);
            this.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.namelayout);
            view.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer quickly:

```
public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    this.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imglayout);
    this.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.namelayout);
    customViewHolder.textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            // Make your toast here, and for the text, use ((TextView) view).getText().toString()
        }
    })
}
```

But I would advice you to have a look about `bind()` method in `ViewHolder` to be called by `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: Thanks @gahfy, let my try it!